# How to detect if label was added to email via gmail api?

Tags: gmail-api

I try to detect if email message got one particular label. Following the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) I do deserialize push message and got historyId
 eg. 390100 but it turns out I can't get exact 390100 history entry.

history.list api has startHistoryId param and docs states that you get all history  **after** that historyId.

However what is even worse 390100 history event is empty (sic!). The real entry with [labelsAdded](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) was *before* that historyId in push notification eg. at 39086 which is **not published**

Tried to workaround and subtract  eg. 15 form 390100 and do history.list with startHistoryId 39085

If I'm in luck and 39085 still exists I will not get 404 and eventually got information that my label was added to message. But that seems like a bad hack for me.

Is there any **reliable way** to know at which point in history label was added, and is there reliable way to search history backwards ?

I also cross posted rant/issue [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4155)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `historyId` you get in the push notification simply represents the current time. So if you use this `historyId` when asking for history, you will not get any results. Use this workflow instead:

1. Save a `historyId`.
2. When you get a push, use the `historyId` you saved in step 1, and you will get all the relevant changes.
3. Save the `hisotryId` you got in the push notification, and use it next time.
4. Repeat step 2.

**Example**

1. I get a starting `historyId` with the [getProfile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile)-operation:

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/profile?fields=historyId&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "historyId": "655156"
}
```

2. I get the push, and [list the history](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) since last time:

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/history?labelId=STARRED&startHistoryId=655156&fields=history%2FlabelsAdded&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "history": [
  {
   "labelsAdded": [
    {
     "message": {
      "id": "151237ed0d001368",
      "threadId": "151237ed0d001368",
      "labelIds": [
       "STARRED",
       "CATEGORY_UPDATES",
       "INBOX"
      ]
     },
     "labelIds": [
      "STARRED"
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

3. Save the `historyId` I got in the push, and use that next time.