# Push notifications that let you watch for changes to Gmail mailboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, gmail, gmail-api

I want to receive email from gmail, if new email comes, my server should get a callback and should get that messages.I tried with gmail push notification ,it says to create a topic , and subscription ,but my problem is ,How to restrict that coming email to be specific to that topic,or I am be wrong, I just want that email to come at my site , I am using ruby-rails

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Ruby on rail expert, however, this could be a potential solution to your question via Labels filtering actions. This can be achieved via the [Users.watch](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/watch) method.

Here is an example provided by a fellow SO of how it can be done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846001/how-to-detect-if-label-was-added-to-email-via-gmail-api/33846761#33846761).

Hope this helps or at least provides you a sense of direction. Cheers!

Comment: But I will only get the messages which are tagged to that label am I right?